# Cryptonote Based Altcoin All Transactions Locked

Tags: altcoin, mining-reward, immature-coins, cryptonote

I've created an altcoin based on the Cryptonote protocol. I have two seed nodes and am mining (successfully) on both of them in order to test the network. However, all mined coins are showing up as "locked". So, for some reason the other node isn't verifying the blocks mined in both cases, however, they must be communicating because their blockchains are synchronised.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Note that there has been a huge vulnerability found in CryptoNote related coins, and I'd recommend you to refrain from using the code now: https://getmonero.org/2017/05/17/disclosure-of-a-major-bug-in-cryptonote-based-currencies.html.

Comment: Does Cryptonote also have a maturation period for block rewards? In Bitcoin block rewards cannot be spent for 100 blocks after they were mined.

Comment: Ahh, I hadn't considered that! Thanks! This would explain why they've gradually become unlocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bitcoin block rewards cannot be spent until they have become "mature". This happens once 100 blocks are mined on top of a block. The idea is that new bitcoins should not be spread around while they may still become invalid due to reorganizations.

In Monero the maturity depth is 60 blocks, which is reached after about two hours. I assume that Cryptonote has a similar delay for block rewards to become spendable.